# Exported project from unity to iOS, while building it's throwing the following error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build

- at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(TinyProfiler2 tinyProfiler, String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, Il2CppCommandLineArguments il2CppCommandLineArguments, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, Boolean throwExceptions) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/il2cpp/Program.cs:line 319
- 

**Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
**

Does anyone knows whats the exact issue here ?

I changed the build settings for both unity-iPhone and unity framework under `Other Linker Flags` to -ld64, but the issue still persists.

earlier the error code what code exited with error code 0, and after the above mentioned issue it says code exited with error code 1.